# How to echo JSON string and replace part of that string at the same time?

Tags: php, json

I'm decoding a JSON response and outputting it in a simple table. Here is a sample of the code:

```
<?php

foreach($results['Events'] as $values)

{
        echo '<tr><td>' . $values['Title'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $values['Details']['Venue'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>Event date:' . $values['Details']['Date'] . '</td></tr>';
}

?>
```

Since `Date` has a timezone added to it, this is what I get:

```
Event title | Event venue | Event date
Event one | Venue one | 2016-01-01T00:00:00
Event two | Venue two | 2016-01-02T00:00:00
Event three | Venue three | 2016-01-03T00:00:00
```

Is there a way to remove "T00:00:00" when echoing the results? This is a desired outcome:

```
Event title | Event venue | Event date
Event one | Venue one | 2016-01-01
Event two | Venue two | 2016-01-02
Event three | Venue three | 2016-01-03
```

Comment: For each date, create a new [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) object, then format is as you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DateTime:

```
$date = new \DateTime($values['Details']['Date']);
echo '<td>Event date:' . $date->format('Y-m-d') . '</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use strtotime()

```
echo '<td>Event date:' . date("Y-m-d",strtotime($values['Details']['Date'])) . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution, thank you. I have accepted bspellmeyer's answer because he was the first one to offer the solution.

Comment: nice to have a single line solution